# how to allow file upload on webview

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, apk

i have social website trying to create webview that can allow upload file
i try different code from internet but nothing work...
when press upload photo on the social website not able to see option for camera, image gallery and file explorer ** button not work **

**this is my MainActivity code :**

```html
    package com.pr.social;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String ShowOrHideWebViewInitialUse = "show";
    private WebView webview ;
    private ProgressBar spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webview =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        spinner = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
        webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
        webview.loadUrl("https://social.domain.com");

    }

    // This allows for a splash screen
    // (and hide elements once the page loads)
    private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView webview, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

            // only make it invisible the FIRST time the app is run
            if (ShowOrHideWebViewInitialUse.equals("show")) {
                webview.setVisibility(webview.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            ShowOrHideWebViewInitialUse = "hide";
            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            view.setVisibility(webview.VISIBLE);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webview.canGoBack()) {
            webview.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

** AndroidManifest.xml code :**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pr.social">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Social"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

        >


        <activity android:name="com.pr.social.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.pr.social.SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You should post minimal html source with such a button. And remove the run code snippet buttons as they serve nothing.

Comment: Also explain why you added a `javascript` tag. And please remove `android-studio` tag.